# How to setup SASS in VueJS project (vue-cli, no webpack config)

Tags: css, sass, vuejs2

**My Repo:** https://github.com/leongaban/VueJS-RobotBuilder

**The course I'm following:** https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=vuejs-fundamentals&author=jim-cooper

This is after I already set it up. Did not remember if there was a sass option.

Anyways currently running into this error:

> Invalid CSS after "<": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ""

I replaced my old `<style> CSS stuff here </style>`

With:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "_robotBuilder.scss";
</style>
```

I also installed the following packages, but I don't see a webpack config file I can edit.

```
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
```

Comment: Are you using the VueCLI v3 to create the project? Also are you trying to write your CSS inside the style tags in the template or simply link to one scss file that includes everything?

Comment: @BryceHowitson I used the CLI, thus I have no webpack config file.. there is a postcss.config.js file in this project however.

Comment: Yeah, that part is confusing. If you need a webpack config you can create (or find the already created) `vue.config.js` All the webpack config is supposed to go in there.  Use `VueCLI3` as part of your Google searches to get better results. When I switched to the new VueCLI [this post](https://dev.to/lynnewritescode/my-scss-setup-within-a-vue-cli-3-project-4jan) really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app.vue (main container) has only this in the style tags

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&subset=latin-ext');
  @import "@/scss/style.scss";
</style>
```

and works just fine.

And this in the vue.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {

    baseUrl: '/',
    outputDir: undefined,
    assetsDir: 'assets',
    runtimeCompiler: undefined,
    productionSourceMap: undefined,
    parallel: true,
    css: {
        modules: false,
        loaderOptions: {}
    }

}
```

Turning off the CSS Modularization "might" have something to do with making it work with the imports...

Answer (score 3):

Just fixed my problem.

I removed this:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "_robotBuilder.scss";
</style>
```

Thought it was strange that an `import` would exist inside a style tag anyways.

Then I cleaned up the .scss file and then just used this import statement inside of the `<script>` section.

`import './_robotBuilder.scss';`

### Update

Just learned you can scope the `<style scoped>` tag so styles only apply to the component.

Comment: I think what you had would have worked, but the error was likely that it couldn't find the file NOT the error you got